# Error .spec.ts en Angular5

Tags: angular5

Tengo el siguiente error provocado en el spec.ts

Lo da esta función.

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UserPanelComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

La descripción es :

```
[Jest]{{ [ERROR ->]'userPanelUserRol' | translate:userPanelUserRol }}</span> </strong> </li>"):
     ng:///DynamicTestModule/UserPanelComponent.html@6:15
    The pipe 'translate' could not be found (" </li> <li> <a href="#" clrDropdownItem>{{ [ERROR ->]'userPanelUserInformation' | translate:userPanelUserInformation }}</a> </li> <li>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/UserPanelComponent.html@10:35
    The pipe 'translate' could not be found (" </li> <li> <a href="#" clrDropdownItem>{{ [ERROR ->]'userPanelPassword' | translate:userPanelPassword }}
</a> </li> <li>"):
 ng:///DynamicTestModule/UserPanelComponent.html@13:35The pipe 'translate' could not be found (" </li> <li> <button class="btn-disconnect"> {{ 
[ERROR ->]'userPanelLogout' | translate:userPanelLogout }}</button> </li></ul>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/UserPanelComponent.html@16:39
```

No entiendo porqué da un error en este archivo si yo no lo he tocado, y tampoco sé que porque da error si todo funciona correctamente.

Nuevo ---->>>>

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateFakeLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { UserPanelComponent } from './user-panel.component';
import { ConfigService } from '../config.service';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

describe('UserPanelComponent', () => {
  let component: UserPanelComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserPanelComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UserPanelComponent],
      providers: [ConfigService],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
        })
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserPanelComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

El error es :

```
Invalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?[object Object]?, ...]
```

El nuevo error es split undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando creaste tu aplicación, tuviste que definir los componentes en un módulo, seguramente los tengas en `app.module.ts`.

Del mismo modo, cuando añadiste ngx-translate, que es un módulo en sí, tuviste que declararlo como importado.

Lo mismo has de hacer en el módulo de pruebas, añadirlo.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UserPanelComponent],
      providers: [{ ConfigService }],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
        })
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Puedes encontrar ejemplos [aquí](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/636#issuecomment-381131231)

Comment: lo importé en la cabecera y puse  imports: [TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateFakeLoader] pero el error no ha cambiado....

Comment: Saludos Pablo, he actualizado la entrada porque sigo teniendo problemas.

Comment: Quita las llaves alrededor de tu servicio, deja `providers: [ConfigService]`

Comment: si hago eso se queja en el fixture, actualizo

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split ' of undefined

Comment: Ahí ya es más complicado que pueda ayudarte: tendría que tener el código de tu componente y el del test completos

Comment: Bueno, muchas gracias por tu interés =).